# Filter un-matched array between 2 array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array.First array is

```
$section_arr[] = array('A', 'B');
$section_arr[] = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$section_arr[] = array('D');
```

And second array is like

```
$data_arr=array(
            '1'=>array('A', 'B'),
            '2'=>array('A', 'B','D'),
            '3'=>array('a', 'b', 'c'),
            '4'=>array('a', 'b'),
            '6'=>array('a'),
            '7'=>array('a','A'),
            '8'=>array('a','B'),
            '7'=>array('A'),
            '9'=>array('D'),
            '10'=>array('D','A'),
            '11'=>array('a', 'b', 'c','D'),
            '12'=>array('a', 'b', 'c','t'),
        );
```

I wanna result like

```
$result=array(
        '2'=>array('A', 'B','D'),
        '6'=>array('t'),
        '7'=>array('a','A'),
        '8'=>array('a','B'),
        '10'=>array('D','A'),
        '11'=>array('a', 'b', 'c','D'),
        '12'=>array('a', 'b', 'c','t'),
    );
```

If the data array's, each array not match with the section_arr, that un-match value I want. If any element of section_arr has found at least 1 or 2 or all, that's not needed in my result. but if any element which is not found in section array that is my desired result. An array can be {A,B} or {a,b,c} or {D}. Suppose  '7'=>array('a','A'), from data_arr- it's my result. if it '7'=>array('A','B','C'), then ok.
I Have tried by the following code.

```
foreach($section_arr as $sec){
           foreach($data_arr as $k=>$data){
               $result_s[$k]=array_diff($sec,$data);
           }
       }
       print_r($result_s);
```

Hope you got what i mean to say.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the logic more clearly? Not sure I understand.

Comment: For example, if I think a single array from data_arr like '1'=>array(A, B), it is correct but it cannot be array(A,B,C). It means every array will be same like section_arr. That means I wanna match every array of data_arr variable with section_arr variable . Which array is not same with any set of section_ arr variable that is the wrong set of data_arr variable. And I wanna filter the wrong set array from data_arr.

Comment: For more example. Forget the section array. I have 3 set. Set1 = A ,B Set 2 = a,b,c and Set3 = D. now the every single array of data_arr cannot be the different of this set. This single array can be a single element like Only A or Only B. But set 1's element and Set 2's element can't stay together in that single array. That means a single array cannot be a, b , B. It can be a or a,b or a b c.

Comment: Case insensitive or why not `$data_arr[4]`?

Comment: $data_arr[4] not because this array elements has found in $section_arra[]=array(a,b,c). If this array would be like a,b,D or a,b,A or a,b,c,D then it's not. Other wise if it holds only a then it will also on that means not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I mean a simple foreach approach, similar to what you started, no `array_` functions or anything, would be this.

```
<?php
$section_arr = [];
$section_arr[] = array('A', 'B');
$section_arr[] = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$section_arr[] = array('D');

$data_arr=array(
            '1'=>array('A', 'B'),
            '2'=>array('A', 'B','D'),
            '3'=>array('a', 'b', 'c'),
            '4'=>array('a', 'b'),
            '6'=>array('t'),
            '7'=>array('a', 'A'),
            '8'=>array('a','B'),
            '9'=>array('A'),
            '10'=>array('D'),
            '11'=>array('D','A'),
            '12'=>array('a', 'b', 'c','D'),
            '13'=>array('a', 'b', 'c','t'),
        );
        
$targeted = [];
foreach($data_arr as $k => $v) {
    $match = false;
    foreach ($section_arr as $k1 => $v1) {
        if (strpos(implode(' ', $v1), implode(' ', $v)) !== false) {
            $match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$match) {
        $targeted[$k] = $v;
    }
}
var_dump(array_keys($targeted)); //2, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it gives the partial result.If $data_arr contain only a partial element of $section_arr, so what will be the result? From your code  '4'=>'a','b' shows the wrong match. But as per my requirement it's correct. Because a and b has found in $section_arr []=a, b, c. Only a or only b or only c or only a,b or only a,c or only b,c is true. But ABC with A or B or D is false. This rule will be followed for every matching.

Comment: What about `'6'=>array('t'),`? Typo?

Comment: '6'=>('t') wrong..coz t didn't match into the $section_arr.

Comment: You're killing me. Fix the data. You repeated index 7 twice. Just like there is no `t` on index 6.

Comment: First condition  ,$data_arr element must be exists into $section_arr. Second condition, D will be single , no other character cannot be set with D. Like a b c can set together or single or any twice. It can't mix with D or AB. Same goes with A B. It can set together of single character but can't mix with another element.

Comment: I updated the answer and provided the data this time. Not sure if this is homework and maybe you are supposed to be using 'recursion' for this? Think the code does what you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
    $arr_diff = array();
            foreach ($data_arr as $key => $val) {
                //print_r($val);
                $arr_match = false;
                foreach ($section_arr as $key2 => $val2) {
                    
                    if (!count(array_diff($val, $val2)) > 0) {
                        $arr_match = true;
                    } 
                }
                if (!$arr_match) {
                    $arr_diff[$key] = $val;
                }
            }
echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr_diff);
```